# SAS Weights of Evidence and Information Values

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that I have generated, the last two columns of which are good and bad flags respectively.  I'm completely new to SAS, and have been tasked with finding the WoEs (and subsequently the IVs) of all of the variables in the dataset in order to rank select.  Is there a relatively simple way to do this?  I can't find anything online that is really of any help to me, and I've been battling for hours!

Comment: Did you read [http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/095-2013.pdf] ?

Comment: Yes - I can't get it to run for my data :(

Comment: Just figuring out a way to count the number of good and bad flags in each column would be a great start - I can derive the rest!

Comment: As this stands it's not an answerable question.  If you've already found resources like the above, please try to implement them and then if you have trouble come back and ask a specific question including the code you've used and what you're having trouble with.  If your questions are more 'how does this work with my data' rather than actually the programming part of it, I'd ask on [stats.se] instead.

Comment: And as I stated, I am a complete newbie to SAS, although I program in several other languages. I have to learn SAS for my job, but, for now without any support. I was merely asking for pointers, and the time I have is limited. Thanks very much for the mark down on my question; I now feel much less stressed.

Comment: Proc freq will count the flags. You may want to post on communities.sas.com - not as restrictive re question format, but you'd get about the same answers until you explain your question better.

Comment: If you know SQL, then look into the PROC SQL statement in SAS. At least that will give you a running start.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I am a SQL programmer, but I have to use SAS where possible for this project.  I'm getting closer to getting the code in Dirk's answer to work, step by painstaking step...

Answer (score 0):

Finally stumbled across what I was looking for:

https://www.observeupdate.com/article/sas-code-for-iv-woe/

Dead easy to understand and adapt for my much larger SQL produced dataset :)

Comment: Links are not considered appropriate answers, as they disappear. Please post the code used as well, preferably your own.

Comment: I'm afraid the code is far too long to fit into a comment/answer, particularly as it took me 5 adapted versions to finally produce the output I required. Mr Penridge, I did eventually cave and make use of proc SQL  I passed my probation review in my now permanent job on Wednesday,  largely because of the solution I provided as outlined above.  I feel that it is a great pity that my Stackoverflow rating was damaged because I asked what was, in essence, a perfectly valid question. Pedagogy should be an incentive to answer questions, quite as much as experts swapping tips with experts.

Comment: Your question does not follow SO rules with respect to presenting a minimum reproducible example and anything you've tried.

Comment: I understand - if I get the time at work, I will at least try to post a methodology. Unfortunately, I don't have access to my work at home, and company rules prevent me from emailing my code out as an attachment!